# Django DRF Viewset URL Reversing Issue - NoReverseMatch for 'orderitem-list

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have `viewset`, namely `OrderItemViewSet`, registered with a `DefaultRouter`. The problem arises when attempting to perform URL reversing for the 'orderitem-list' endpoint, where I consistently encounter a `NoReverseMatch` error.

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsOrderOwner]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Order.objects.filter(user=user)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ("update", "partial_update", "destroy"):
            self.permission_classes += [IsOrderPending]
        return super().get_permissions()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ("create", "update", "partial_update", "destroy"):
            return OrderWriteSerializer
        return OrderReadSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(user=user)

class OrderItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsOrderItemOwner]
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        order_id = self.kwargs["order_id"]
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(order__id=order_id)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ("create", "update", "partial_update", "destroy"):
            self.permission_classes += [IsOrderItemPending]

        return super().get_permissions()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=self.kwargs["order_id"])
        serializer.save(order=order)
```

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"", OrderViewSet, basename="order")
router.register(r"^(?P<order_id>\d+)/order-items", OrderItemViewSet, basename="orderitem")
    
urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls)),]
```

Then this is the error I'm getting:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'orderitem-list' with keyword arguments '{'order_id': 1}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/orders/^(?P<order_id>\\d+)/order-items\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/orders/^(?P<o...
```

Comment: Please try and fix the formatting, it will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Could you add the Viewset's definition as well?

Comment: I added the viewset of orderitem. Can you check again please ?